# T-SQL to determine "out of sequence" records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL server and I need to determine records that are "out of sequence" from a table.

I'll explain through an example.
I have the following table structure:

```
OrderNumber OrderStatus EventDateTime
0001522989  22          2014-04-14 05:49:25.4414243
0001522989  26          2014-04-14 05:51:16.7047485
0001522989  23          2014-04-14 05:51:17.8602798
0001522990  23          2014-04-14 05:51:19.9603575
0001522990  24          2014-04-14 05:52:06.5803494
0001522990  24          2014-04-14 05:52:06.5803494
```

Now I need to produce a list of OrderNumbers that were sent "out of order".
So in this example, the list will contain only one value: "0001522989".

Order 0001522990 was sent in the correct sequence (first status 23, then status 24 and then again status 24 (this doesn't count as "out of sequence")).

Order 0001522989 was not sent in the correct sequence (first status 22, then status 26 and then status 23).

Any idea on how I can accomplish this?

I added the possibility of an order to send out the same status twice in a row (this shouldn't count as "out of sequence")

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 onwards...

```
SELECT
  OrderNumber
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNumber ORDER BY OrderStatus, EventDateTime  )   AS sequenceCorrect,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNumber ORDER BY              EventDateTime)   AS sequenceActual
  FROM
    yourTable
)
  AS yourTableSequenced
WHERE
  sequenceCorrect <> sequenceActual
GROUP BY
  OrderNumber
ORDER BY
  OrderNumber
```

**EDIT :** Oops, I forgot the `WHERE` clause, should work now ;)

Comment: Hi MatBailie. Thanks, it seems to work but I found out an additional issue. It can happen that the same order status number is sent out twice. The result of your statement also returns those orders, while they are not actually out of sequence (so ex. Order 0001 sends status "22" at 10u00 and sends status "22" at 10u05. This shouldn't be detected as "out of sequence". Is there a way to include this as well?

Comment: @Rise_against - Yes, just add the `EventDateTime` to the first `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

If the question boils down to:

> Find all invoice numbers where there is a lower status number with a higher date

you can do:

```
select OrderNumber 
from Orders o1
where exists (select * from Orders o2 
              where o2.OrderNumber = o1.OrderNumber
                and o2.OrderStatus >= o1.OrderStatus 
                and o2.EventDateTime < o1.EventDateTime)
```

Comment: Gotta give it to ya, overlooking the fact that it has to be the same order number, you gotta do it.

Comment: Oops (quite a big one :))